# How to get password prompt from ssh in Perl script

Tags: linux, ssh, perl

When I execute this from command line, I get prompted for joe's password (which is what I want):

```
ssh -t 192.168.1.32 'scp joe@192.168.1.31:/etc/hosts /tmp'
```

When I try to run the same command from a perl script, it just hangs there (with no prompt):

```
`ssh -t 192.168.1.32 'scp joe\@192.168.1.31:/etc/hosts /tmp'`;
```

How can I make this work from a Perl script?

Note: No, I cannot use key-based authentication for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use Expect. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1366802

(and the Expect module FAQ on this topic http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.15/Expect.pod#I_want_to_automate_password_entry_for_su/ssh/scp/rsh/... )

Answer (score 2):

You could use Perl's [`Net::SCP`](http://search.cpan.org/~ivan/Net-SCP-0.08/SCP.pm) for this, which would be the cleanest (all-perl, no external command calls) solution.

Or you could do as [Andrew suggests](https://serverfault.com/a/554816/32986) and use Expect (which is probably quicker).

Or you could `fork()`, `exec()`, and `waitpid()` (letting your `scp` command have the terminal your Perl script is running from so it can get passwords from you, which is a nice old-school Unix-y approach, but way more work than I'd be willing to do personally).

[TIMTOWTDI.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There's_more_than_one_way_to_do_it) :-)

Comment: For the expect route, http://stackoverflow.com/a/2851593

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same kind of issues some time ago.

The reason it hangs is because ssh spawns a terminal for the password input. Perl can can not catch this terminal (for reason). "Password" string is never seen by perl.

It's better to use the libs ( Net::SSH2 libs or something similar).